# Wrong limits of very simple problems in Mathematica running on Ubuntu

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to find the limit$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$$ with the assumption $x\in \mathbb{R}$ on my Macbook Air, and I got `Indeterminate`, but on my friend's Ubuntu desktop (both running version 11) he got 0. Very puzzling, we tried even a simpler function $$ \dfrac{1}{x} $$ and his computer shows $\infty$, instead of `Indeterminate`. What's going on? Is there some change in the settings?

Comment: What version of Mathematica? M11, M11.1, M11.2, or M11.3? And what is the exact code you tried?

Comment: I am using 11.3, and he is using 11.0

Comment: Limit was modified in 11.2, fixing the issues he's seeing in M11.0. Basically, in M11.0, Limit assumes a particular direction, while M11.2 does not.

Comment: But this is rather trivial functions, I suspect these things would be correct from the first version, we wouldn't have to wait for 11.2 versions. I suspect is it something to do with OS ?

Comment: By the way, in the second case we get $\infty$, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In M11.2, [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit) was modified to support multivariate limits. In previous versions, [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit) assumed a particular direction when computing limits. In particular, $x \to 0$ was assumed to approach 0 from positive values.  Since there is no canonical direction to use for multivariate limits, [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit) no longer assumes a direction when computing limits. So in M11.0:

```
Limit[1/x, x->0]
```

was assumed to actual mean:

```
Limit[1/x, x->0, Direction->"FromAbove"]
```

> ∞

Note that the other direction *(for real x)* is:

```
Limit[1/x, x->0, Direction->"FromBelow"]
```

> -∞

In M11.2, no such direction assumption is made, and since the limit is not the same for both directions we get:

```
Limit[1/x, x->0]
```

> Indeterminate

Comment: Thanks! But your answer is rather scary, thousands of papers written using Mathematica, with this basic flaw ? I am not able to digest it, nonetheless I'll accepted your answer. Given that mathematica incorporates variables as complex numbers to begin with, I thought that it genuinely understood limits, but I might be dead wrong.

Comment: Also, it may give you the impression that limit exists at a point, where it doesn't. This is scary indeed.

Comment: Limits are fundamentally directional-based. Even the multivariate case is specialized by assuming one is approaching from real space. Since version 11.2 the default assumption, for univariate and multivariate, is that the approach is in real space. Prior to that, there was no support for real multivariate limits, and the default direction for univariate was to approach from the east (unless the limit is at an infinity).